# Fails to get the location on Android mobile

Tags: android, mobile, locationmanager, android-location

Actually my problem is sometimes i can get the location and sometimes i can't get the location on Android real device. I used following code for getting the location,

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

I need to get the location when my application starts up. I don't know why sometimes it fails. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you using BroadCastReceiver ?

Comment: Then how you are fetching GPS Co-Ordinates on Application Starts up ?

Comment: @ Android, Actually I have a class with extends `Application`. And I have mentioned into AndroidManifest file. I used this code in to that class.

Comment: Increase your power requirements and make sure you test where you can get a network or gps signal.  If that helps, then it's simply a case of the sensors not getting enough reception to know the location.

Comment: jsmith sounds right - the GPS probably just can't get reception to get the location.  Try moving the device outside, or in a known location where GPS connectivity is stronger.  If the app gets the location more often, then you're all set.  If you absolutely need a location, however, may I suggest an `AsyncTask` that will keep trying to get GPS co-ordinates until it finally finds some?

Comment: @ jsmith, Well answer. Its working fine when I increase power requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@jsmith** commented on my quesion,

> Increase your power requirements and make sure you test where you can
>   get a network or gps signal. If that helps, then it's simply a case of
>   the sensors not getting enough reception to know the location.

This is the right answer for my question. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to request for 'Location Updates', use this function after declaring the `LocationManager`:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
```

and you have to let the class implements `LocationListener` then add this function:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//get the location here
}
```

If you don't want to get the location repeatedly, after you get the location you have to stop the 'Location Updates' this way:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

in case you want the application always listen for the 'Location Updates', you better request for updates in `onResume()` and remove the updates in `onPause()` & `onDestroy()`

Good Luck